# SqlDataAdapter Not Updating

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, console

I am trying to update `TableTwo` using a `DataTable` built using `TableOne`.
The relationship between tables is a foreign column called `TableOneId` inside `TableTwo`.

I used the following code sample to make this work: [*Performing Batch Operations Using DataAdapters (MSDN)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx)

The `DataTable` is populated in another `Public Shared` function.

I can't figure out what is wrong. No error messages are reported. The watch reveals that the `DataTable` is loaded with data.

**The `DataTable` is defined as:**

```
Public MyDataTable As New DataTable

Public Shared Sub DefineDataTable()

    Dim ErrorEmail As New ErrorEmailMessageClass
    With ErrorEmail
        Try
            Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.MyDB)
                MyDataTable.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Column1", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Column2", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Column3", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Column4", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            .WriteError("Sub DefineDataTable", ex.Message)
        End Try
    End With
End Sub
```

**But the `SqlDataAdapter` is not updating:**

```
Public Shared Sub UpdateTable()
    Dim ErrorEmail As New ErrorEmailMessageClass

    With ErrorEmail
        Try
            Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.MyDB)
                connection.Open()

                Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()

                'Set the UPDATE command and parameters.
                adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand( _
                  "UPDATE Schema.TableTwo " _
                  & "SET " _
                  & "Column1=@Column1, " _
                  & "Column2=@Column2, " _
                  & "Column3=@Column3, " _
                  & "Column4=@Column4 " _
                  & "WHERE TableOneId=@ID;", connection)
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "Column1")
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "Column2")
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Column3", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "Column3")
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Column4", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "Column4")
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ID")
                adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters

                ' Set the batch size.
                adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0

                ' Execute the update.
                adapter.Update(MyDataTable)

                connection.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            .WriteError("Sub UpdateTable", ex.Message)
        End Try
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I gotta tell you that using `With` like that is really weird.

Comment: Pre-established coding standards.

Comment: Is the problem that it's not updating the database, or it's not updating the datatable after the update?

Comment: Just for kicks, can you try opening the connection after creating the command? Try opening the connection right before you execute the update.

Comment: Correct it is not updating the Database. Remember that the DataTable is built using TableOne, but we want to update TableTwo in the Database.

Comment: Opening the connection after creating the command did not work either.

Comment: Do you have this code, or similar code working in other situations? Is the problem limited to this particular scenario (updating TableTwo from DataTable built using TableOne)?

Comment: No, this is the first time I used BatchUpdate.I used the following code sample:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As you've commented in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152273/batch-update-table-across-non-linked-sql-servers/7153047#7153047), here is my answer:*

You should set the [UpdateBatchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property of the SqlDataAdapter to 0 (unlimited).
I don't see a way to update table2 without looping table1.

Here is a sample code to show you one way to achieve this:

```
Public Sub BatchUpdate(ByVal table1 As DataTable)
    Dim connectionStringServer2 As String = GetConnectionString()

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionStringServer2)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()

        'Set the UPDATE command and parameters'
        adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand( _
          "UPDATE Table2 SET " _
          & "NAME=@NAME,Date=@Date  WHERE TableOneId=@TableOneId;", _
          connection)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", _
          SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", _
          SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "Date")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@TableOneId", _
        SqlDbType.Int, 0, "TableOneId")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = _
          UpdateRowSource.None

        ' Set the batch size,' 
        ' try to update all rows in a single round-trip to the server'
        adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0
        ' You might want to increase the UpdateCommand's CommandTimeout as well'
        adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandTimeout = 600 '10 minutes'

        Dim table2 As New DataTable("table2")
        table2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)))
        table2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Date", GetType(Date)))
        table2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TableOneId", GetType(Int32)))

        ' copy content from table1 to table2'
        For Each row As DataRow In table1.Rows
            Dim newRow = table2.NewRow
            newRow("TableOneId") = row("ID")
            newRow("Name") = row("Name")
            newRow("Date") = row("Date")
            table2.Rows.Add(newRow)    
            ' note: i have not tested following, but it might work or give you a clue'
            newRow.AcceptChanges()
            newRow.SetModified()
        Next

        ' Execute the update'
        AddHandler adapter.RowUpdated, _
        New SqlRowUpdatedEventHandler(AddressOf OnRowUpdated)

        adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 5000   
        adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandTimeout = 6000
        adapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = True                      
        adapter.Update(table2)

    End Using
End Sub
Private Shared Sub OnRowUpdated(sender As Object, args As SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs)
    If args.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
        args.Row.RowError = "Optimistic Concurrency Violation!"
        args.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No rows updated and SQL Server Profiler reveals no connection attempt.
But I am connecting to same DB while populating the DataTable, so it is not a connection problem.

Comment: The DataTable is full of Data. 300k rows. The Data is populated in another public shared function.

Comment: @Internet: Is this in a Module? Because `MyDataTable` is not explicitely set as shared and you are accessing it from a shared method. Where are you calling `DefineDataTable`?

Comment: @Internet: I've edited my answer according to my last comment.

Comment: This is a console app. The DataTable is declared in Module MainModule.
Both the Update and Define DataTable are set inside Public Class.
The DataTable is not being overwritten as the watch reveals the columns and the row count at the break point of the update.

Comment: @Internet: I asked because you've tagged this question `ASP.NET`. Besides you wouldn't detect this multithreading issue on debugging because there is only one user(you).

Comment: Yes, I tagged as asp.net because I am an ASP.net Developer.

Comment: @Internet: Thank you for accepting my answer. But the [Bounty is not tied to accepting answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying the command type?:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

> "If you look in Reflector, you'll see that _commandType isn't
>   initialized to anything."

Comment: Connection was set at the end of adapter sql statement.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. Updated my answer. It's the only other thing I could think of...

Comment: I am not able to find _commandType in Reflector. I can see _commandSet: SqlCommandSet and many others.

Comment: @James: according to your last edit, have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx) and you'll see that CommandType.Text is default if nothing else is specified.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Yes, I saw your comment. Maybe it was an older article I was looking at. The code looks right, so I'm kind of clutching at straws :)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of issues that could cause the data to not be updating.

First - are you trying to Update existing rows in TableTwo or are you trying to Insert new records.  If you want to insert, using the update command will not work.

Second - are there any modified rows in TableOne?  One mistake I've seen is that once someone has populated the datatable, they call Table.AcceptChanges() which sets all rowstates to Unchanged.  A quick test to check that you have modified data would be to run this code before the update:

```
For Each row as DataRow In MyDataTable.Rows
  If row.RowState = DataRowState.Modified Then
    MsgBox("Found a modified row!")

    Exit For
  End If
Next
```