# Batch Update Table Across Non Linked SQL Servers

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to update a table across "non-linked" SQL servers using:
C# or VB.net and ADO.net `SqlDataAdapter`.

I need to use `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

**Very Important: I need to use `BatchUpdate` and avoid looping through the `DataTable`.**

The table designs in Server 1 differ from table design in Server 2.

**Source Table:**

```
Server 1. Table 1
ID INT
NAME Varchar(30)
Date DateTime
```

**Destination Table:**

```
Server 2. Table 2
ID INT
TableOneId INT (Foreign Key from Server 1. Table 1)
NAME Varchar(30)
Date DateTime
```

I need a sample on how to update table 2 on server 2 using `SqlDataAdapter`, or an alternative batch method.

Comment: Do you want to avoid looping the DataTable or avoid several roundtrips to the database?

Comment: I want to use BatchUpdate since for performance issues is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [UpdateBatchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property of the SqlDataAdapter to 0 (unlimited).
I don't see a way to update table2 without looping table1.

Here is a sample code to show you one way to achieve this:

```
Public Sub BatchUpdate(ByVal table1 As DataTable)
    Dim connectionStringServer2 As String = GetConnectionString()

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionStringServer2)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()

        'Set the UPDATE command and parameters'
        adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand( _
          "UPDATE Table2 SET " _
          & "NAME=@NAME,Date=@Date  WHERE TableOneId=@TableOneId;", _
          connection)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", _
          SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", _
          SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "Date")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@TableOneId", _
        SqlDbType.Int, 0, "TableOneId")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = _
          UpdateRowSource.None

        ' Set the batch size,' 
        ' try to update all rows in a single round-trip to the server'
        adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0

        Dim table2 As New DataTable("table2")
        table2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)))
        table2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Date", GetType(Date)))
        table2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TableOneId", GetType(Int32)))

        ' copy content from table1 to table2'
        For Each row As DataRow In table1.Rows
            Dim newRow = table2.NewRow
            newRow("TableOneId") = row("ID")
            newRow("Name") = row("Name")
            newRow("Date") = row("Date")
            table2.Rows.Add(newRow)    
            ' note: i have not tested following, but it might work or give you a clue'
            newRow.AcceptChanges()
            newRow.SetModified()
        Next
        ' Execute the update'
        adapter.Update(table2)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126356/sqldataadapter-not-updating and submit the same answer and I will give you the bounty.

Comment: @Internet: Ok, i've posted this answer at your other question as well and deleted my other approaches there.

Answer (score 0):

Since your DataTables have different schemas, you'll have to loop through each row in the DataTable to get it to port correctly from one to the other.

If it were me, that would be the last thing I was concerned with, though.  That'll be fast. The biggest issues are memory usage and network speed.

You're going to have to have two DataTables, two DataAdapters and two trips to the database (one per server).  That's a lot of work to do.  The looping should be less of a concern.

(Although, I agree that batch update on server 2's DataTable would be wise.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer 2008 or later, an alternative to using SqlDataAdapter might be to use table valued parameters :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

So the steps would be :

1) read source data into a DataTable

2) write a new stored proc in the destination database which will perform the importing. This would take a table valued parameter as one of its parameters. You pass the DataTable you created in step 1) to this stored proc.

Pros : full control over the import process. Potentially better performance than using SqlDataAdapter. e.g. you could write T-SQL to update the complete table in one go.

Cons : need to write some T-SQL (may not be a problem if you are comfortable with this).